# make sure to call FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize() although initialized

Tags: android, facebook

This is my activity:

```
import com.apprikot.kooora.controller.interfaces.HasTwitter;
import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.TwitterAuthClient;

public class SocialActivity extends BaseActivity implements HasTwitter {
    protected CallbackManager mCallbackManager;
    protected TwitterAuthClient mTwitterAuthClient;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        mTwitterAuthClient = new TwitterAuthClient();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        mCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        mTwitterAuthClient.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    @Override
    public TwitterAuthClient getTwitterAuthClient() {
        return mTwitterAuthClient;
    }
}
```

The simple solution that's not working with me, is to put the initialization before the `setContentView`, which is already done in my case.

This is the main activity manifest declaration (it extends the SocialActivity above):

```
<activity
    android:name=".controller.activities.MainActivity"
    android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
    android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"/>
```

Finally, this is the crash I'm getting:

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.sikooora/com.facebook.FacebookActivity}: The SDK has not been initialized, make sure to call FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize() first.\n\tat android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2853)\n\tat android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2882)\n\tat android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2314)\n\tat android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:157)\n\tat android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1289)\n\tat android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)\n\tat android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)\n\tat android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5317)\n\tat java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)\n\tat java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)\n\tat com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)\n\tat com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)\n\tat dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)\nCaused by: The SDK has not been initialized, make sure to call FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize() first.\n\tat com.facebook.internal.Validate.sdkInitialized(Validate.java:136)\n\tat com.facebook.FacebookSdk.getApplicationContext(FacebookSdk.java:427)\n\tat com.facebook.AccessTokenManager.getInstance(AccessTokenManager.java:84)\n\tat com.facebook.AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(AccessToken.java:144)\n\tat com.facebook.login.LoginClient.authorize(LoginClient.java:121)\n\tat com.facebook.login.LoginClient.startOrContinueAuth(LoginClient.java:108)\n\tat com.facebook.login.LoginFragment.onResume(LoginFragment.java:152)\n\tat android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performResume(Fragment.java:2020)\n\tat android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1107)\n\tat android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252)\n\tat android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1234)\n\tat android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchResume(FragmentManager.java:2056)\n\tat android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchResume(FragmentController.java:196)\n\tat android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onResumeFragments(FragmentActivity.java:505)\n\tat android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onPostResume(FragmentActivity.java:494)\n\tat android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5417)\n\tat android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2830)

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm having the same error

Comment: @Misters it seems moving the initialization statement to the application class inside `onCreate()` will solve it.

Comment: When you say 'application class' you mean inheriting from android.app.Application?